# Thread can not get access to the RichTextBox.Lines

Tags: c#

```
 Thread main;

    public void bomb()
    {
        string link = textBox1.Text;


        for (int i = 0; i <= richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://" + link + "/");
            WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy(this.richTextBox1.Lines[i], false);
            //request.Proxy = myproxy;
            request.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { label1.Text = i.ToString(); });
        }


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        main = new Thread(bomb);
        main.Start();

    }
```

But line:
richTextBox1.Lines.Length
and
richTextBox1.Lines.[i]

Generate error:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than >the thread it was created on.

If I want get text from richtextbox all is OK, but if I want get lines i get error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Invoke` to access `richTextBox1.Lines` as you do with `label1`

```
var lines = (string[])richTextBox1.Invoke(
                           (Func<string[]>)(() => this.richTextBox1.Lines));
```

Same is true also for `textBox1`